# Elements in the array not recognized

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom, appendchild

```js
    var userInput = prompt('Which fruit would you like?');
      var fruitList = ["banana", 'strawberries', "mango"];

      for(var i=0; i<fruitList.length; i++);
        if(userInput == fruitList[i]){
          alert("Sorry, we are out of " + userInput);
        }else{
          var userFruit = document.createElement('li');
          userFruit.textContent = userInput;
          var fruits = document.getElementById('list');
          fruits.appendChild(userFruit);
        }
```

```html
    <div id="list"></div>
```

It looks like for loop is not working as it's adding the user input into the list but it doesn't recognize elements from the array. The list which I didn't add here has `id="list"` and it has the three elements from the array. Thank you!

```
  var userInput = prompt('Which fruit would you like?');
  var fruitList = ["banana", 'strawberries', "mango"];

  for(var i=0; i<fruitList.length; i++);
    if(userInput == fruitList[i]){
      alert("Sorry, we are out of " + userInput);
    }else{
      var userFruit = document.createElement('li');
      userFruit.textContent = userInput;
      var fruits = document.getElementById('list');
      fruits.appendChild(userFruit);
    }
```

Comment: The for loop is definitely working, I just tested it and the prompt asks what fruit, I answer and if it is in the array, it lists the item in the div with the id of `list`

Comment: Thanks for checking. Whats not working is, when the user insputs banana, strawberries or mango it doesnt show "sorry, we are out of it" but still adds the item to the list. Well, yeah, actually, its the if sentence thats not working, not the for loop. I guess I constructed the question wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is that your if section is outside your for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the curly brackets to the for loop... It is not needed however it is tidier in nature. Your issue was syntax as you had a semi colon at the end of the for loops terminating the loop.

***Change this*** --> `for(var i=0; i<fruitList.length; i++);`

***To this*** --> `for(var i=0; i<fruitList.length; i++){` or `for(var i=0; i<fruitList.length; i++)`

***NOTE ON EDIT*:** Moved the variables outside the for loop and assigned the `innerHTML` or you could use `textContent` to the variable outside the loop. Then in the for loop, appended the created `li` item to the `ul` parent.

[image]

```js
const userInput = prompt('Which fruit would you like?');
const fruitList = ["banana", 'strawberries', "mango"];
const fruits = document.getElementById('list');
const userFruit = document.createElement('li')
userFruit.innerHTML = userInput;

for (let i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {
  if (userInput === fruitList[i]) {
    alert("Sorry, we are out of " + userInput);
  } else {
    fruits.append(userFruit);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the message. Yes, it works now, however, I need to figure out why it adds element to the list twice though.

Comment: Because you are appendingChild(), I changed the line to add innerHTML and used the userInput to set selection

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay, changed the answer to more cover the question and intent I think you were going for... You wanted to create a list item in a unordered list and append that to your document. The reason the doubling was going on was because you were assigning the value inside the for loop. I moved the constants or variables, outside the loop and then appended the created element to the parent element. Think this what you were after...

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code more make sense.

Is it similar to what you expect?

```js
var userInput = prompt('Which fruit would you like?');
var fruitList = ["banana", 'strawberries', "mango"];
let newItem = false;
for (let i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {
  if (userInput == fruitList[i]) {
    newItem = false;
    alert("Sorry, we are out of " + userInput);
  } else {
    newItem = true;
  }
}
if (newItem) {

  let userFruit = document.createElement('li');
  userFruit.innerHTML = userInput
  let fruits = document.getElementById('list');
  fruits.appendChild(userFruit);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the message. Its funny what it does. It still adds banana and strawberries to the list even after showing the alert message. Only mango is not added to the list. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it compares your entry against all the fruits in the array, so any time there isn't a much it will add it to the list. You may instead use `includes` method to check the existence of the element in the array.

```js
  var userInput = prompt('Which fruit would you like?');

  var fruitList = ["banana", 'strawberries', "mango"];

  if(fruitList.includes(userInput)) {
    alert("Sorry, we are out of " + userInput);
  }
  else {
    var userFruit = document.createElement('li');
    userFruit.textContent = userInput;
    var fruits = document.getElementById('list');
    fruits.appendChild(userFruit);
  }
```

```html
 <div id="list"></div>
```